# Maven Build fail due to missing dependency - Beginner

Tags: java, spring, maven, google-code

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project CarProject: Could not resolve dependen
     cies for project CarProject:CarProject:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts
    could not be resolved: com.googlecode.sslplugin:struts2-ssl-plugin:jar:1.2.1, o
     rg.springframework:org.springframework.web.servlet:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE, org.spring
    framework:org.springframework.context:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE, javax.transaction:com.s
     pringsource.javax.transaction:jar:1.1.0, com.sun:tools:jar:1.6.0: Failure to fin
       d com.googlecode.sslplugin:struts2-ssl-plugin:jar:1.2.1 in http://repo1.maven.or
      g/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted
     until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help
      1]
```

Seems like there are more than one dependencies missing, How should i add them ? Is there a place where i could get the dependency or is there a particular standard way of writing it ?

Comment: Possibilities: (1) com.googlecode.sslplugin:struts2-ssl-plugin:jar is not available (2) if available, it cannot be traced - either it is not in the same folder or your CLASSPATH variable does not include its containing folder

Comment: Paste your pom.xml file.

Comment: you mentioned beginner and hence this question may be redundant, but do you have a local maven repository.(Artifactory or Nexus). Otherwise the problem is simple, you need to specify specific repositories for some of your dependecies. Something like this.<repository>
02     <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.release</id>
03     <name>EBR Spring Release Repository</name>
04     <url>http:// repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release</url>
05 </repository>

Comment: See this link for more details. http://blog.springsource.com/2009/12/02/obtaining-spring-3-artifacts-with-maven/.Under repository section. Also you need to do the same for your google deps. Find the repository and add them to your pom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

org.springframework.web.servlet = spring-web or spring-webmvc or both depending on what you need from it

org.springframework.context = spring-context

com.springsource.javax.transaction comes from the [SpringSource enterprise bundle repository](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/bundle/version/detail?name=com.springsource.javax.transaction&version=1.1.0).

struts2-ssl-plugin isn't in central. You'll have to find it in another repository, [install it locally](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html), install it on your own repository, like [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/), or make it a [system-scoped dependency](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies).

tools is your JRE. Maven mostly shouldn't be trying to download it. You probably have a bad dependency somewhere.

Comment: `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository> -DgroupId=com.googlecode.sslplugin -DartifactId=struts2-ssl-plugin -Dversion=1.2.1 ` Is it some thing like this ? But this doesn't work

Comment: Almost. The "file" parameter should point to the jar file you want to install.

Comment: Is it possible for you to give me an example ?

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest jar file from following location
http://code.google.com/p/struts2-ssl-plugin/downloads/list

Run the following command
**Example** for struts2-ssl-plugin-1.2.1.jar file

mvn install:install-file -Dfile=E:\Java\Meteors\struts2-ssl-plugin-1.2.1.jar -DgroupId=com.googlecode.sslplugin -DartifactId=struts2-ssl-plugin -Dversion=1.2.1 -Dpackaging=jar